# Fastest Way To Format a Plain Text Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-io, formatting, performance

I have a huge plain text document, about 700kb which is very big for plain texts and I need to format it on cloud converting it to HTML, but the only things that I need to replace, format to HTML so it can be displayed by the browser, are **bold** and *italic*. For bold at the plain text they are like this:

```
Not on bold... **bold text here** not bold here
```

And italic like this:

```
Not italic... *italic text* no italic
```

Just like StackOverflow does for their formatting, but the problem is that I need to make it a lot faster, since the text is so big... One of my ideas was to add a page slide, so I the script just need to format some part of the text, not it all, then after the user changes the page the script would be called again, but the problem is how I can make the code for this all?

Comment: 700Kb is not HUGE by any stretch of the imagination....

Comment: Not for a binary, but for a plain text it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is

```
function boldAndItalicize(text) {
  return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/(\*+)([^*]{1,1024})(\*+)/g,
               function (whole, open, content, close) {
                 if (open.length === close.length) {
                   switch (open.length) {
                     case 1: return '<i>' + content + '</i>';
                     case 2: return '<b>' + content + '</b>';
                   }
                 }
                 return whole;
               });
}
```

too slow?

If you want to break it up, you do still need to scan to the break point, to make sure you don't split inside an italicized or bolded section.

Comment: How I need to insert the text file on the `text` argument?

Comment: @Nathan, your best bet is probably to fetch it via `XmlHTTPRequest`.

Comment: But it's a local file, not remote. How can I make it?

Comment: @Nathan, I don't know what you mean by local file.  If it's on a machine on which you can put a webserver, then you can serve it.  If it's on the user's machine, then you shouldn't be trying to use a user's browser to steal local files from their machine.

Comment: When I said local, I mean a file that is on the server :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to divide it in many divs and try to find a way to apply the formatting to each when they become visible (i.e. the user scrolls and they enter the content area).

I have no idea on how to do it, but you may find something similar already done in Jquery and grab some code.

Something like this for example:
http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/